# Vim command S is missing

Tags: vim

In Vim I once was able to select multiple lines with v, and then press S to replace all those lines and directly go to insert mode.

However, when I now press these buttons, nothing happens. How can I get that behavior back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility that you have the Surround plugin installed which uses `S` and `s`.

Alternatively, you can use `c` for the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd> should be working for you.

A good place to start troubleshooting is to see what the following command shows you:

```
:verbose vmap S
```